# MirrorMaker2 automated consumer offset sync for mirromaker2 as consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

is there any way to sync mm2 itself consumer offset? since it is not using __consumer_offsets topics to track, instead it is using  mm2-offsets.src.internal to track the offset and by default, MM2 won't sync this internal topic.
Here's an example for the issue I am facing:

- purple MM2 is replicating topics from kafka 1,
- orange MM2 is replicating topics from kafka1 → kafka2 with automated consumer offset sync
- orange MM2 can not sync offset for purple MM2 since purple MM2 is using kafka connet internal offset topic to manage the offset, in my case it’s mm2-offsets.src.internal
- after migrating MM2 from kafka1 to kafka 2, it will reset all topics since it can not find the original topic offset in kafka2,  this issue is fixed if using __consumer_offset, however this is not the case for MM2 itself.

[image]

Comment: also tried setting auto.offset.reset = latest, it will work without reset from beginning, however, data loss might be expected